# How to install gcc 6.3 on 17.10 64bit Desktop

Tags: nvidia, cuda

How to  install gcc 6.3 on 17.10 64bit Desktop  and replace original gcc with a link?( for  cuda 9.1 of  nvidia)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6
export HOST_COMPILER=gcc-6
```

This allows you to keep gcc-7 but you can still build cuda and tensorflow with gcc-6.

Comment: This is how I got everything compiled when using cuda version 9.1 and libcudnn version 7.1.2 and recent tensorflow master branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc g++
gcc –version

sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y && \
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot -y && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y && \
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6
```

Comment: That doesnt install gcc 6.3.0, it install the latest gcc in the repository

Comment: The first command indeed tries to gcc, but it also removes cuda and nvidia-390 (or whatever is your driver) because they depend on it, which is against the original goal.